# Minimum of an approximated function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, maxima-minima

I have the following function
$$ f(x,y) = 100(y-x^2)^2 + (1-x)^2$$
which has minimum at point $(1,1)$. I was asked to find it's quadratic approximation by using Taylor's theorem. By using the derivatives
$$f_x=400(x^3-xy)+2x-2$$
$$f_y=200(y-x^2)$$
$$f_{xx}=400(3x^2-y)+2$$
$$f_{yy}=200$$
$$f_{xy}=-400x$$

I found Taylor's expansion around $(0,0)$ as follows:
$$Q(x, y) = f(0,0)+f_x (0,0)x +f_y(0,0)y+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(0,0)x^2+f_{xy}xy + \frac{1}{2} f_{yy}(0,0)y^2 $$

$$=1 -2x +0y +\frac{1}{2}2x^2+0xy+\frac{1}{2}200y^2$$
$$=x^2-2x+100y^2+1$$

However, this new function has a minimum at point $(1,0)$. My profesor told me that this can't be right and that the new approximated function $Q$ should have min at the same point $(1,1)$.

Im not sure why is this true and I cant find any mistakes in my solution. Am I wrong in thinking that it makes sense that the new fucntion $Q$ doesnt have the same minima with the old?

Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Surely you want to take the Taylor expansion around (1,1) so that the approximation is good around the minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Taylor expansion is to be performed around the minimum $(1,1)$. Denote $\epsilon = O( y-1)=O(x-1)$. Then, the quadratic approximation can be obtained as follows,

$$ f(x,y) = 100(y-x^2)^2 + (1-x)^2$$
$$= 100[y-1-(x^2-1)]^2 + (1-x)^2$$
$$= 100[(y-1)^2-2(y-1)(x^2-1)+(x^2-1)^2] + (1-x)^2$$
$$= 100[(y-1)^2-2(y-1)(x-1)(x+1)+(x-1)^2(x+1)^2] + (1-x)^2$$
$$= 100[(y-1)^2-4(y-1)(x-1)+4(x-1)^2] + (1-x)^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$
$$= 100(y-2x+1)^2 + (1-x)^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$

Note, the approximate function still has its minimum at $(1,1)$.

---

Edit:

$$f_x=400(x^3-xy)+2x-2 = 0$$
$$f_y=200(y-x^2)=0$$
$$f_{xx}=400(3x^2-y)+2 = 800+2$$
$$f_{yy}=200$$
$$f_{xy}=-400x=-400$$

Put it together,

$$f(x, y) = 0+f_x (x-1) +f_y(y-1)+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(x-1)^2+f_{xy}(x-1)(y-1) + \frac{1}{2} f_{yy}(y-1)^2 $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(800+2)(x-1)^2-400(x-1)(y-1) + 100 (y-1)^2 $$
$$ =(x-1)^2+ 400(x-1)^2-400(x-1)(y-1) + 100 (y-1)^2 $$
$$ =(x-1)^2+ 100(y-2x+1)^2 $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is something wrong with what i did though? I retried it and took the expansion around $(1,1)$ and the minimum still isnt the same as the initial function's. Are they supposed to have their minimum at the same point?

Comment: @Thomas - See the edits in the answer using your method. As you can see, it leads to the same result.

Comment: Thanks a ton, found my mistake :) Now it has indeed the minima at the same point. Have a good day

Comment: @Thomas - you're welcome.

Comment: Another question that came to my mind, if you can answer. When we face a problem like this, where we want to find the minima of an approximated function, why is it "necessary" to perform Taylor's expansion around the known minima, in our case $(1,1)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Thomas - you can do the Taylor expansion around any point, but as an approximation it will be closest near that point, and be a poorer approximation as you move away from that point.  If you are interested in the behaviour around a minimum, logically you need to calculate the expansion around that minimum point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer MilesB. So it is normal that if we take the expansion around $(0,0)$ the minima of the approximated function isn't $(1,1)$ anymore, right?

Answer (score 0):

Define $x=1+u, y=1+v$

$$\begin{array}\\
f(1+u,1+v) 
&= 100((1+v)-(1+u)^2)^2 + (1-(1+u))^2\\
&= 100(1+v-1-2u-u^2)^2 + (-u)^2\\
&= 100(v-2u-u^2)^2 + u^2\\
&= 100(v^2+4u^2+u^4-4uv-2u^2v+4u^3)+u^2\\
&\approx 100(v^2-4uv)+401u^2\\
&= 100v(v-4u)+401u^2\\
&= 100(y-1)(y-1-4(x-1))+401(x-1)^2\\
&= 100(y-1)(y-4x+3)+401(x-1)^2\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is something wrong with what i did though? I retried it and took the expansion around $(1,1)$ and the minimum still isnt the same as the initial function's. Are they supposed to have their minimum at the same point?

Comment: @Thomas - what did you get for each of the five derivatives ($f_x$ etc) evaluated at (1,1)?  It should then just be a question of $Q(x,y) = f(1,1) + f_x(1,1)(x-1) + ...$

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured it out :)

Answer (score -1):

Since
$f(x,y) = 100(y-x^2)^2 + (1-x)^2
$,
around (1, 1) we have

$\begin{array}\\
f(1+x,1+y) 
&= 100((1+y)-(1+x)^2)^2 + (1-(1+x))^2\\
&= 100((1+y)-(1+2x+x^2))^2 + x^2\\
&= 100(y-2x-x^2)^2 + x^2\\
&= 100(y^2+4x^2+x^4-4xy-2x^2y+4x^3)+x^2\\
&\approx 100(y^2-4xy)+x^2\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: This answer doesn't look just from thinking about the last line, because it doesn't have minimum at (0,0) which we would expect for your change of variable.  I can see your error is your second line where you've incorrectly expanded $(1-(1+x))^2$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is something wrong with what i did though? I retried it and took the expansion around (1,1) and the minimum still isnt the same as the initial function's. Are they supposed to have their minimum at the same point?

Comment: I found an error and fixed it. Hope this is ok.

Comment: Its ok yeah, altough im not familiar with your way. I always use Taylors theorem the way i did in my post. Thanks a lot for the answer !